# SwiftUI change opacity of selected view

Tags: swiftui

Okay so I'm trying to change the opacity on the selected image. This is how my code looks like

```
struct TestView: View {

  @State var opacity: CGFloat = 0.5
  let columns = [GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 1), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 1), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 1)]
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 1) {
            ForEach(0..<90, id: \.self) { _ in
                Image("placeholder")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .clipped()
                    .opacity(opacity)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        opacity = 1
                    }
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

However this is changing all the images back to 1 instead of the selected image. How would I be able to get this to work.

Comment: You need to tag your image in the loop. If you don't tag them, then all have the same ID. A simple way to do that would be to just have an incrementing `index`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're not identifying which image is selected. Instead when you tap the image it just sets the current opacity for *all* the views to 1.

```swift
    @State var selectedItem: Int? = nil

    let columns = [GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 1), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 1), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 1)]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 1) {
                ForEach(0..<90, id: \.self) { row in
                    Image("placeholder")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .clipped()
                        .opacity(selectedItem == row ? 0.5 : 1) // Change opacity based on selection
                        .onTapGesture {
                            // Set the selected row when the image is tapped.
                            selectedItem = row
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code sets the `selectedItem` state var when the image is tapped. Then it checks if the current image is the selected image. If it is, then it sets the opacity to 0.5, if not it sets it to 1.

Comment: You can also make these changes by adding a .animation modifier to the view. More on that here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-an-explicit-animation